# VBA - Method or data member not found when opening an excel file from access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a small application that connects to a SQL server and downloads some of the data to Excel. It works fine in my computer but in the computer of one of my coworkers I get a "Method or Data member not found" error when trying to change the content of a cell in the excel spreadsheet.

This is the code that fails in my coworker computer, the line that has the error is the last line:

```
Public Function ExportRequest(strSupplier As String, intSupplier As Integer, _
    strOutPath As String, iEmpty As Integer, strManager As String, _
    ichkVolume As Integer, iframeVolume As Integer, ichkMatNum As Integer) As String

   On Error GoTo err_Handler
   
   ' Excel object variables
   Dim appExcel As Excel.application
   Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
   Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim wksvol As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim wsRange As Excel.Range
   Dim wksvolRange As Excel.Range
   
   Dim sTemplate As String
   Dim sTempFile As String
   Dim sOutput As String
      
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim sSQL As String
   Dim sDateFrom As String
   Dim sDateTo As String
   Dim lRecords As Long
   Dim iRow As Integer
   Dim iCol As Integer
   Dim iFld As Integer
   Dim intYear As Integer
   
   Const cStartRow As Byte = 3
   Const cStartColumn As Byte = 1
      
   intYear = year(Now)
      
   DoCmd.Hourglass True
   
   ' set to break on all errors
   application.SetOption "Error Trapping", 0
   
   ' start with a clean file built from the template file
   
   sTemplate = ap_GetConfig("NegTemplatePath") & ap_GetConfig("NegTemplate")
   
   sOutput = strOutPath & "\Price Template " & strSupplier & "-2020" & ".xlsm"
   
   If Dir(sOutput) <> "" Then Kill sOutput
   FileCopy sTemplate, sOutput
   
   ' Create the Excel Applicaiton, Workbook and Worksheet and Database object
   Set appExcel = Excel.application
   Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(sOutput)
   wbk.Sheets("Price List").Visible = xlSheetVisible
   Set wks = appExcel.Worksheets("Price List")
   wks.UnProtect Password:="irishstout"
   wks.Cells(1, 2) = strSupplier
```

Hopefully someone has run into something similar?

Comment: If you comment out the error handler is that last line the one highlighted ?

Comment: Should really be `Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("Price List")`

Comment: Also: `Set appExcel = New Excel.application` rather than just `Set appExcel = Excel.application`

Comment: @TimWilliams I commented the line with error and a different line pop's up:

inline `wks.Columns("E:G"). EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: @Rory thanks! I made that change, but still have the same error :(

Comment: I don't see that line in your post, but there should be no space before the `.`  Also helps to note exactly what the error message is.

Comment: @TimWilliams That line is further down the function, the space before inline `.` was a typo on my reply. The whole text of the error message is: Method or data member not found (Error 461)

Comment: Without the space there's nothing obvious wrong with that line.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Office object model, all methods, properties, and events follow a hierarchical structure. Usually, the `Application` object usually initializes top level items. All others would derive from its descendants. Therefore, the `Excel.Application` would not contain properties for worksheets or ranges. See examples below.

[**Excel**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model)

- **Methods**: Application > Workbooks > Add / Open ...
- **Properties**: Application > Workbook > Worksheets / Queries / Path ...
- **Events**: Application > Workbook > Activate / BeforeClose ...

  ```
  Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
  Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\MyWorkbook.xlsx")
  Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("My Sheet")

  wks.Name = "My New Name"
  ```

[**Word**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/word-object-model-overview?view=vs-2019)

- **Methods**: Application > Add / Open ...
- **Properties**: Application > Document > Paragraphs / Table / Bookmarks ...

  ```
  Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\MyDocument.docx")
  Set wdPara = wdDoc.Paragraphs(1)

  wdDoc.Tables.Add(NumRows=3, NumColumns=3)
  ```

[**Access**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access)

- **Methods**:

  - Application > OpenCurrentDatabase > CurrentDb ...
  - Application > DoCmd > OpenForm / OpenReport ...
- **Properties:**

  - Application > CurrentDb > TableDefs / QueryDefs ...
  - Application > CurrentProject > AllForms / AllReports ...
- **Events**: Application > CurrentProject > AllForms > Form > AfterUpdate / BeforeClose ...

  ```
  Set appAccess = New Access.Application
  Set accFile = appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Path\MyDatabase.accdb")
  Set db = accFile.CurrentDb()

  appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm("My Form")
  ```

Comment: Hi, I corrected that and I still get the error. I have to make notice that the error only happens to a single user, could the excel version have anything to do with it?

Comment: Are you using the `New` keyword when initializing `Excel.Application`? Otherwise, find exact problematic line by removing one line at a time.

Comment: I used the inline `New` keyword and I got the same result, what's most intriguing is that it only happens in a single computer.

Comment: Once again please debug and find the line causing the error. I cannot see how this is a version or CPU issue.

Comment: I did the debugging and this is what happens:[Error Message]( https://imgur.com/VYOMajg )

Comment: In VBA IDE of machine that raises this error, under Tools \ References, is "Microsoft Excel X.X Object Library" checked? This is required for [early binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) as you do here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have it checked and still not working.

Comment: Try removing all worksheet protections and then re-run code.

Comment: What I ended up doing was deleting and restoring the DB from the most recent working back up and that get rid of the issue, it was, pretty weird.